# VB.Net 2010 Installer

Tags: javascript, vb.net, installation

I'm currently trying to create a Visual Basic 2010 Installer for an application that I recently created. The idea of the Installer will push the necessary JavaScript Files to the designated location and also create the program for users to use.

Problem: 
I am trying to incorporate the Javascript files into my Installer so I can push it into the user's files - of course, checking if that file structure is installed or not, but I do not know how. Any help would be beneficial!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside File System create a custom folder and you can use these Folder Properties [System Folder Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372057%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the default location to specify the path that you need. Drop all your files inside that custom folder and you are done.